# Poner meses en español en consulta

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy tratando de usar el `SET lc_time_names` para poner los meses en español, el cual me funciona muy bien directo en phpMyAdmin, pero cuando creo la consulta en PHP no me funciona.

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
 $sql ="SET lc_time_names = 'es_CO';";

 $sql .=" SELECT MonthName(carreraXestado.carXest_fechaHora) AS mes, 
 count(carreraXestado.carXest_car_id) AS num_carreras";

 $sql .=" FROM carreraXestado";

 $sql .=" WHERE carreraXestado.carXest_estCar_id = 6";

 $sql .=" GROUP BY mes";        
 $rs = $this->baseArca->Sql_libre($sql);               
 return $rs;
```

Comment: *no me de funciona.*: ¿qué sucede?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que hace el método `Sql_libre`? Es posible que ahí este el problema.

Comment: Esto es lo que hace el Sql_libre:
public function Sql_libre($sql){
        $k=0; $list=null;
        $this->cerrar();
        $this->conecta();
        $rs = $this->ejecuta($sql);
        if(is_int($rs)){
            return $rs;
        }
        if($rs){
        while ($dato = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
            $list[$k]=$dato;
            $k++;            
        }
        }else{
           
        }
        $this->cerrar();
        return $list;
    }

Comment: public function conecta()
  {
     $this->host="localhost";
     $this->user="prueba";
     $this->pass="prueba";
     $this->bd="prueba";
     $this->inicio();
  }

Comment: public function inicio()
  {
       $this->conexion = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->pass,$this->bd) or die("Error de conexion");    
  }

Answer (score 0):

Eso es una variable de sesión. PHPMyAdmin te permite fijar variables de sesión que duran (doh!) toda la sesión. En PDO, en cambio, cada sentencia es una sesión por sí misma.

Solución, tienes que inicializar tu conexión a PDO fijando el parámetro de `lc_time_names`

```
$db=new PDO(
        "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mibase",
        "miuser",
        "pass",
        [
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET lc_time_names='es_CO'" 
        ]
);
```